# Hiding my server's real URL from attackers in my app using the signing key?

Tags: android

This is just an idea and I would like to ask will it work and what are the dangers (if any).

So let's say **I have an application with an API access** to my server.

I don't want anybody to use the API, **except legitimate Google Play users who downloaded the application from the official Google Play store**, I don't want hackers, repackers and third party app stores users to use my API.

---

The idea is the following:

I would make **my API's url** like this:

```
myserver.com/12345/api_resource
```

Whereas `12345` is the first five characters of my app signing key.

So if I think this right, anybody who repacks the app with his own key would have a different (false) server url access like:

```
myserver.com/abcde/api_resource
```

Whereas `abcde` is the first five characters of his own key.

**The real signing key, thus the real url couldn't be extracted from the source code, am I right on this?**

Of course, it could be extracted from monitoring network calls, that is a different topic, I just want to achieve the things I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The real signing key, thus the real url couldn't be extracted from the source code, am I right on this?

I don't know how you are defining the "real signing key".

Your public key is available via `Signature` from `PackageManager`. You could certainly use data derived from this as part of a URL. A naive repacker would wind up using their own public key, and this would fail your Web requests. However, a more sophisticated attacker could determine what you're doing by reverse-engineering (decompiling) your app. And that's in addition the network monitoring approach that you mention.

Comment: The real signing key is which I'm using to sign my application with when distributing via Google Play. So how does the more sophisticated attacker could determine such key?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: If you do not get the data from `PackageManager`, your first five characters will have to be compiled into your app, such as being part of your source code. That's not significantly more secure than using `AdamV` or `12345` as those five characters. So, between decompiling or network monitoring, they can get those five characters.